# Why do GCC and Clang not produce a warning for unused const variables in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, compiler-warnings

I have the following code example:

```
class Myclass
{
public:
    Myclass(int a): m_a {a} {
        m_a += 2;
    }

private:
    int m_a;    
};

const Myclass var = 3;

int main()
{

}
```

I can compile this code and both gcc and clang does not raise any "unused-const-variable" warning which is weird for me. Why compiler does not raise "unused-const-variable" in this case ?

Also,
Making the constructor "constexpr" results with the following behaviours:
For GCC : Still there is no "unused-const-variable" warning.
For Clang: It start to raise "unused-const-variable".

So, another question is : Why do compilers behave differently from each other? And which one is the most correct?

Used GCC version: 11.3.0
Used Clang version: 14.0.0-1

> clang++ -c -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra test.cpp -o test.o

Used commands in case of GCC :

> g++ -c -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra test.cpp -o test.o

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`var` is a global variable. The compiler cannot know that the variable will not be used by some other translation unit than the one it is currently compiling.

Comment: But const implies internal linkage in C++ by default, but not implies internal linkage in C. So, It cannot be used in another compilation unit. Right ?

Comment: Using `static const` it may raise the warning, not tested

Comment: IMHO adding static keyword will not change anything. Because the linkage is internal by default. Edit: It didn't help.

Comment: @user3104363: It's due to before typed `class enum : <type>` were a thing, the recommended C++ practice to define typed constants was through `<type> const` "variables". Hence you'll find a lot of code out there in the wild that defines tokens and constants through such `const` variables. Which was also the reason for internal linkage being the default, so that the compiler can optimize away the memory loads into instruction constants. If you'd emit "unused variable" warnings for that, you'd spam the compiling logs for every project using headers defining constants that way.